# Downloading files via PHP

Tags: php, curl, cron

I have problem with downloading files via PHP.

The funny thing is that I can not trace the problem. The code works good for some websites and not good with other. It is loop in PHP that downloads the backup files from websites (there is delay with sleep before requests).

Why I can not trace the problem?
Because when I run manually the code, it works (downloads the file). And when it  is run by CRON, sometimes it downloads the file, sometimes it does NOT download the file (only downloads 2 empty new lines).

The download is with curl (I have also tried with different code with fsockopen and fread).

Does anyone have an idea on how I can solve this?

Headers are removed with CURL by setting the correct option.

```
function fetch_url($url) {
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

    if ($cookiejar != '')  {
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiejar);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiejar);
    }

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER , false);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST , false);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER , true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12');
    $con = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);
    return $con;
}

echo fetch_url('http://www.example.com/zip.zip');
```

Comment: Security question: do the webservers containing those backups have a way to grant you access as a legitimate user - or does it not matter if Joe Public downloads a copy of these backups?

Comment: You should use curl_error and log it to txt file or something, then you will be able to trace why its not working, there could be allot of reasons (too large of files mainly over 2GB's, wrong headers, corrupts or incomplete data, gzip encodings or timeouts)...log every curl request & also put some security in place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php to display information about the curl request

```
echo curl_errno($c);
print_r(curl_getinfo($c));
```

Also, Maybe it's in your code elsewhere, but I'm not seeing any content type headers for your echoing of the file

```
$file = fetch_url('http://www.example.com/zip.zip');
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="zip.zip"');
header("Content-length: " . strlen($file));
echo $file;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks will try that. If it does not work, will post the question again with the dumped information.

Comment: the problem is not in the headers because I actually save the downloaded contents to file.